# Error Invalid Data Package Version in the OLEDB source of Data Flow Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, msbi

I have created a SSIS Package containing a Data Flow task in Visual Studio 2012. The source and destination servers are both 2012. But while running the following error is popping up:

[SRC - XYZ [103]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Error occured. 
Details: Invalid DataPackage Version".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create SSIS packages for SQL Server 2012, you need to use Visual Studio 2010.

Visual Studio 2012 will create packages that can only be used by SQL Server 2014.